# User logged in (ID), in back. Jhipster 4.1.1

Tags: jhipster

In a Jhipster 4.4.1 application with Mongodb, JWT.
I need the user logged in for a query, and I do not know how I can retrieve it in a java controller (Resource)
In SecurityUtils I do not see how to get the ID

```
public static String getCurrentUserLogin() {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
    String userName = null;
    if (authentication != null) {
        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
            UserDetails springSecurityUser = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
            userName = springSecurityUser.getUsername();
        } else if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof String) {
            userName = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
        }
    }
    return userName;
}
```

I can capture the user ID logged in, without consulting the database.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you need the current user, then you can query against `login` as given by `getCurrentUserLogin()` in your question because it's [unique](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/4150df13414dbd86db279729cf2eabf325dd3738/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/domain/_User.java#L84) anyway.

If you really want the ID, then have a poke around [AccountResource](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/e7ac67f810925b5a03dacf1a7a0ee8d0a427cb26/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/web/rest/_AccountResource.java#L151) and you'll see that `UserDTO` and `User` have a `.getID()` method.

Comment: For me within my Resource this line of code allowed me to acquire ID of currently logged user. I am just only not 100% sure if this is/was the correct way on how to do this:

Long id = userService.getUserWithAuthoritiesByLogin(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin()).get().getId();